# Trouble in conversion from jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert the code below from jquery to javascript but I can not figure out how I can do. can anyone help me?

```
$('*').each(function(i, el){    

    var $element = $(el),
    color = $element.css('background-color');

    if(!~$.inArray(color, colors))
        colors.push(color);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#1
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*')).forEach(function (node) {
  var color = node.style.backgroundColor;
  if (color && !~colors.indexOf(color)) {
    colors.push(color);
  }
});

#2
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')),
    len = elements.length,
    i, node, color;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  node = elements[i];
  color = node.style.backgroundColor;

  if (color && !~colors.indexOf(color)) {
    colors.push(color);
  }
}
```

[http://jsbin.com/miyida/1/](http://jsbin.com/miyida/1/edit?html,js,console)